# How to use Git with two differents repositories with and without ssh authentification?

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, gitlab

I have got a problem:

I have to work with to projects :

- The first is on a local gitlab and needs an ssh authentication
- The second is on a simple git server (without gitlab or other tool like it) which don't need ssh authentication

All is fine, when I'm working with the gitlab's projects, but when I'm trying to pull, push, fetch projects not on gitlab server: git bash returns :

> Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa':

But I don't need any ssh authentication !

When I run git remote -v for the gitlab project, git bash returns :

> $ git remote -v
>
> origin  http://xxxx/yyyy-tools/yyyy-demat-purge.git (fetch)
>
> origin  http://xxxx/yyyy-tools/yyyy-demat-purge.git (push)

When I run git remote -v for the other repo (not on gitlab) it returns :

> $ git remote -v
>
> origin  git@myIp:/repository/yyyy/yyyy-order-parent.git (fetch)
>
> origin  git@myIp:/repository/yyyy/yyyy-order-parent.git (push)

So I think that it's a not a remote configuration problem...

When I try to bypass the question of the ssh authentication to access to the repository not on gitlab, git bash returns :

> $ git remote -v
>
> origin  git@ip:/repository/yyyy/yyyy-order-parent.git (fetch)
>
> origin  git@ip:/repository/yyyy/yyyy-order-parent.git (push)
>
> $ git fetch origin
>
> Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
>
> git@ip's password:
>
> GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Here is the content of the **non-gitlab** ~/.ssh/config file

> Host DEV_XX1
>
> HostName DEV_XX1
>
> User gitUser
>
> IdentityFile /home/hostUser/.ssh/id_rsa
>
> IdentitiesOnly yes
>
> Host myIp
>
> User hostUser
>
> ProxyCommand ssh deploy@myIp -W %h:%p

How can I resolve this problem ? I think that it can exist a configuration solution, but which one?

Thank you !

Comment: Could you add the output of ``git remote -v`` for both of your repos ?

Comment: Which protocols are you using for each for the repositories? [The Protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols). Depending on this it could be a `ssh` config thing or a `git` config thing ^^

Comment: @jibe I just edited my post :)

Comment: Same answer for @AnimiVulpis

Comment: So on the **non-gitlab** server the error puts **GitLab:** in the front? Did you try configuring `ssh` with the `~/.ssh/config` file?

Comment: See (again) my question to get the content of the .ssh/config file existing on the non-gitlab server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, in your second project, the remote url might be set to a ssh url,something like git@ip/.... (run the command: "git config -l" to see, pay attention to "remote.origin.url=")

You need to edit the url to the one that uses http or some other protocol provided by your git server. Use the follow command to edit:

```
git remote set-url origin https://yourusername@servername/username/project.git
```

In summary, there're two ways to work this out. Firstly, use "remote set-url" command as my answer above, to change your url to http. Secondly, use ssh authentication. You neet to generate a public/private key pair, then store the public key to git server (if your git server support it). Finally, create a ~/.ssh/config file with following content:

```
Host hostname host_ip 
HostName host_ip 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/privatekey
User yourusername
```

This way, the authentication will be automatically taken care of

Comment: Thank you for your response. As you can see in my post just edited the remote urls are in HTTP for the gitlab repository and are using SSH for the other repository.

Comment: But, for information, before I was just working with the repository without gitlab using SSH and it worked well...

Comment: I might need more information to dig in, after you enter paraphrase for "Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa':", Were you able to proceed pull, push?

Comment: I have tried to reverse the protocols beetwen the two repositories, now i can well access to gitlab repository via SSH.
But when I'm trying to access to the other repo via HTTP, a popup asking authentication appears to log myself to the repo... But I haven't any user or password...

And to answer to your last comment: yes, once gitlab repository joined via ssh I succed to push pull fetch etc.

Comment: I think I got it,
There're two ways to work this out
1. Using http
use "remote set-url" command as my answer above, to change your url to http

2. Using ssh
- First you neet to generate a public/private key pair
- Then store the public key to git server (if your git server support it)
- create a ~/.ssh/config file with following content:

Host hostname host_ip
        HostName host_ip
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/privatekey
        User yourusername

This way, the authenticate will be automatically taken care of

Comment: I just try to add my ssh public key in the *authorized-keys* file. But whithout any success... 
There is yet a config file (see my updated answer)

Comment: It looks like the authentication failed. 

Firstly, we should make sure the public/private key pair works. Can you try login via ssh only, using the key pair. You can run "ssh [ip] -i /path/to/privatekey".

By the way, which environment do you perform git commands, Linux or Windows?

Comment: Just to specify : I just got the information that gitlab repository and non-gitlab repository are hosted in the same server...

Comment: Yes thank you for your help : The problem was that non-gitlab and gitlab repositories were on the same VM. And the non-gitlab repository wasn't configure correctly. It has been install just 3 years ago....